CDS View Geolocation Data - Coordinates get interpreted as measures
we have the requirement for a geomap in an accounting dashboard.
For this we need geolocation data which we get from the table geot005.
The geodata gets selected just fine, but gets interpreted as measures with a warning in the SAP Analytics Cloud that simply states "Location Dimension required"

As of now our dimension looks like this:
define view ZD_SD_CUSTLOC as select from geot005 {
@Semantics.address.country: true
key land1 as Country,
@Semantics.geoLocation.longitude: true
longitude,
@Semantics.geoLocation.latitude: true
latitude,
altitude
}

Is there an additional annotation needed or is there another requirement we don't know of? I looked it up and our BW version should definitely support the use of Geomaps.
